# Use Hadamard Cauchy to find the radius of convergence for the power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

I think I know the process of solving, but I'm having trouble applying it to these series.

(a)  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^{-n^3}z^n$

(b)  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-i)^{2n}}{n3^n}$

(c)  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3^n+i^n)(z-2)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^3}\right|}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-n^2}=\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{e^{-1}}=e$$

thus, Cauchy-Hadamard:

$$R=\frac{1}{e}=e^{-1}\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Twisted idea for (b) and (c):
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3^n+i^n)(z-2)^n$$
can be calculated explicitly because is a sum of two geometric series. Use now that the radius of convergence is the distance from the center to the nearest singularity of $f$.
$$g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(z-i)^{2n}}{n3^n}$$
is only a bit more difficult:
$$
g'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(z - i)^{2n - 1}}{3^n} =
\frac{(z - i)}3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(z - i)^{2(n - 1)}}{3^{n - 1}}
$$
has the same radius of convergence and also can be calculated explicitly...